# Creating a dataframe based on the matching of 2 lists

Tags: r, loops, updating

I have two lists (one or more of the columns of these list will be a list as well) and I am matching values between each only where the column names match.   Then based on matching, I would like the values either TRUE or FALSE outputted to a DF.  I was using a loop in my code and ignoring the fist column which is an ID column. I provided some code to reproduce the example and desired output, but my script is more specific to my data so you can get a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
List1 <- list(ID = 123, L1 = 89, L2 = 2, L3 = c(2.5, 3.5, 4))

List2 <- list(income = c(1,2,3,4,5), L1 = c(0,0,0,89,0), L10 = c(3,3,3,3,3),
              L2 = c(2,55,55,55,55), L3 = c(2.5, 8, 8, 4, 8))
```

Desired results:
DF1

```
income  L1  L10 L2  L3
    1   0   0   1   1
    2   0   0   0   0
    3   0   0   0   0
    4   1   0   0   1
    5   0   0   0   0
```

My code:

```
NBPmatrix <- function(x){

     nbp <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(black), ncol = ncol(black))
     colnames(nbp) <- names(black)

     index <- nbp[, match(colnames(x), colnames(nbp), nomatch = 0)]
     for(i in 2:length(nbp))
     nbp[index] <- grepl(black[[i]], x[i], ignore.case = TRUE)  
     return(nbp)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why L3 in the 4th row should be 1?

Comment: That is an error. I meant to add one of the other values in the L3 from List1.

Comment: You should respond to comments by editing the body of the question.